# Multiple FOR and one DO for batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Could someone explain to me why this fails?

```
FOR %l IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) FOR %a IN (temp\*.upp) DO upp1.exe c%l %a
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a required `do`, as with:

```
for %x in (1,2) do for %y in (a,b) do echo %x%y
```

which outputs:

```
1a
1b
2a
2b
```

If you leave out the first `do` (as you have done), all you get is:

```
for was unexpected at this time.
```

You need, for your particular case:

```
FOR %l IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO FOR %a IN (temp*.upp) DO upp1.exe c%l %a
REM                           ==
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly and made perfect sense.

Comment: @Manny90: In case you are not aware, you can [formally accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it actually solves your problem.